# JGroups, TCP_NIO multiple messages sent to nowhere

Tags: nio, jgroups

Messages sent to ports I never specified in my configuration file.

this is my config:

```
[10-Jan-2011 11:02:22.917 GMT] ERROR org.jgroups.protocols.TCP_NIO  - failed sending message to 192.168.50.41:8851 (116 bytes): java.lang.Exception: connection to 192.168.50.41:8851 could not be established
[10-Jan-2011 11:02:22.917 GMT] WARN  org.jgroups.blocks.ConnectionTableNIO  - Connection is not running, discarding message
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have a `port_range` of `2`, so every discovery message is sent to all of the `initial_hosts` defined in `TCPPING`, plus `port_range`, e.g.

```
TCPPING.initial_hosts=A[1000],B[1000]
port_range=2
```

will send discovery requests to `A:1000-1002`, `B:1000-1002`.

`TCPPING` is used at startup for initial discovery and by `MERGE2` (not in your stack)...